# mapper parsing exception in elastic search nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

i am a newbie to elasticsearch and was trying to index some json objects. My json object looks like this:

```
{
"name": "ABC",
"age":22,
"education": "XYZ",
"metadata": {
asset1:{
fingerprintID: "dnadklwdkl",
image: "URL"
}
}
}
```

Here, the metadata is given by the user and can be anything, null, an array, object of different things. other field like name, age, education are consistent but not metadata.so, i am having trouble indexing it. i was following this link: https://www.compose.com/articles/getting-started-with-elasticsearch-and-node/ and creating index for the data and pushing to the elastic server running locally. I have around 1 million  json data like above fetched from a database and have no idea how the metadata will be. On creating the index and running the service, i get this error:

```
{ error:
   { root_cause: [ [Object] ],
     type: 'mapper_parsing_exception',
     reason: 'failed to parse',
     caused_by:
      { type: 'illegal_argument_exception',
        reason:
         'Limit of total fields [1000] has been exceeded while adding new fields [2]' } },
```

some of received json data from database have been pushed to the server successfully, but most of them are not. How do i handle this issue? Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it seems like some of your JSON objects have a lot of fields. By default, Elasticsearch allows only 1000 total fields within an object to prevent [mapping explosion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings). If you know what you are doing, you can simply increase this limitation by doing:

```json
PUT your_index/_settings
{
  "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 9999
}
```